# html - How to dynamic change base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I am try to transmit live video stream to server and show on web page. Well, I successfully show my image on the html page, but my image is freeze. The image will change only when I press refresh button on the browser. How to make it show like a video stream? Following is my snippet:

```js
var socket = io();

socket.on('liveCam', function(url) {

  var old_url = '';
  var diff = strcmp(url , old_url);
  old_url = url;

  console.log('diff =', diff);
  var src_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + url; 
  setInterval(setimagesrc(src_url), 50);

});

function setimagesrc(uurl){
  $('#image').attr('src', uurl);
}

function strcmp ( str1, str2 ) {
  return str1 == str2 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

<h1>streaming</h1>
<p>
  <img src="" id="image">
</p>
```

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the **setInterval** function evaluates an expression. What you did there is that you call the **setimagesrc** function to be executed in the set interval. This will cause the **setimagesrc** to be executed only once. What you have to do there is to add a reference to the **setimagesrc** function and use global variables or to use an anonymous function in the **setInterval** that will call the **setimagesrc** with the parameters.

Example 1:

```
setInterval(setimagesrc, 50);

function setimagesrc(){
  $('#image').attr('src', src_url );
}
```

Example 2:

```
setInterval(function(){setimagesrc(src_url)}, 50);
```

I prefer the second way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake, but it's still not working. I had tried to use image from source file by `setTimeout(function(){setimagesrc(src_url)}, 50);`, and it work. but for base64 image, it's still freeze except refresh my page.

Comment: Are you sure that the base64 that you get from the service is correct with no errors? Because I have tried that with base64 images and it is working fine for me in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Yes, my base64 source is correct. However, I found the problem is that my source url is not updated, and I solved it with your answer. Thanks for your help.